# How to execute saveAs Menuitem in pdf to convert pdf to word document using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

On clicking a button in pdf how to create an new word document and save it destination path using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Unless you find a specific library, i believe it's not possible.

If you find any, let us know.